# How to find an element in the span with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have a problem when I use `xpath` to find an element. Actually there were two elements. For example `bundle1` and `bundle11` it will append (number resources) the numbers were dynamic.

In the code I used the following, but both `bundle1` and `bundle11` were got. In the code `elementName` if use `bundle1` then both `bundle1` and `bundle11` will got through the `Xpath`. the `text()` will be `bundle11` (33 Resources) or `bundle11` (33 Resources)

```
return this.viewPortElement.findElement(
By.xpath(".//table//td/div/div//span[span[startswith(text(),'"+elementName+"')]]"));        }
```

was there any way to locate the element? In the web page the corresponding `html` like following

```
<span title="bundle11 (33 Resources)">bundle1 (33 Resources)</span>

<span title="bundle11 (33 Resources)">bundle11 (33 Resources)</span>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if you are asking how to get the 'title' either /@title or .Attribute["title"].value might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is by appending white space after the number :

```
return this.viewPortElement
           .findElement(
                By.xpath(".//table//td/div/div//span[span[startswith(text(),'"
                            +elementName
                            +" ')]]"
                            //^notice white space added here
                        ));
```

this way, given `elementName` variable assigned value `1` for example, you can match `bundle1` only without unintentionally matching `bundle11`.